# How to configure Flume 1.x (flume-ng) in failover mode?

Tags: hadoop, load-balancing, flume

There is plenty of information available on configuring Flume (0,9x) nodes in failover mode in CDH3.

But the configuration format for Flume (1.x) configuration in CDH4 is completely different.
How to configure Flume 1.x (flume-ng) in failover mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In flume-ng you can define group of so-called "sinks" (event consumers), which all connected to one channel, and specify "failover" policy for this group, so if one of the sinks fails, events will be redirected to another.

Suppose we have two sinks - **main_sink** and **backup_sink**, and both configured to consume events from one channel and to deliver events to some destination. We set priority of **main_sink** greater than priority of **backup_sink**, so Flume will forward events from channel to **main_sink** as long as it works. However, if **main_sink** fails, Flume will relegate it to failed sinks pool where it will be assigned a cool down period. Meanwhile events from channel will be forwarded to **backup_sink**.

Full example may look like this:

```
# channels
agent.channels = mem_channel
agent.channels.mem_channel.type = memory

# sources
agent.sources = event_source
agent.sources.event_source.type = avro
agent.sources.event_source.bind = 127.0.0.1
agent.sources.event_source.port = 10000
agent.sources.event_source.channels = mem_channel

# sinks
agent.sinks = main_sink backup_sink

agent.sinks.main_sink.type = avro
agent.sinks.main_sink.hostname = 127.0.0.1
agent.sinks.main_sink.port = 10001
agent.sinks.main_sink.channel = mem_channel

agent.sinks.backup_sink.type = avro
agent.sinks.backup_sink.hostname = 127.0.0.1
agent.sinks.backup_sink.port = 10002
agent.sinks.backup_sink.channel = mem_channel

# sink groups    
agent.sinkgroups = failover_group
agent.sinkgroups.failover_group.sinks = main_sink backup_sink
agent.sinkgroups.failover_group.processor.type = failover
agent.sinkgroups.failover_group.processor.priority.main_sink = 10
agent.sinkgroups.failover_group.processor.priority.backup_sink = 5
```

You can find more details on the subject in [Flume User Guide](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#flume-sink-processors).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that and post the results.

Comment: Even with these settings, I was unable to see the sinks running on specified port using 'netstat' command.

Also, is it possible to have the (failover) sinks running on different servers?

Comment: One more thing, I'm trying to use AsyncHbaseSink. Not Avro sync.

Comment: I'm using avro sinks and sources to glue multiple agents. Thanks! :)

Comment: is there a fail over mechanism for the agent itself? Lets say my server running flume agent crashes.